# Use of imperfect tense to mean conditional

Tags: pretérito-imperfecto, condicional

I saw this used in some celebrity interview and in a tv show I'm watching. Basically, the imperfect tense is used interchangeably with the conditional tense to mean a conditional statement.

My questions are: How do you know when you can use this? Can you always answer a hypothetical question with the imperfect tense?

The examples I've heard:

(Jugando a casar, matar o follar)
Le preguntaron ¿qué har**ías**? y él contesta:

> Yo me casar**ía** con Bella, a esta la mat**aba** y con esta me cas**aba**
>   (See [video](https://youtu.be/da7HLkPp7pI?t=188))

That was the first time I heard of it so I didn't think much of it but then I saw it again in [*Vis a vis*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vis_a_vis_(serie_de_televisi%C3%B3n)):

Les preguntaron a las presas ¿qué harías si salieras de aquí mañana? y todas contestaron con el condicional, salvo una, la Rizos, que dijo:

> Me peg**aba** un baño en bolas en el mar

Comment: It's had this meaning for a while actually — Portuguese, Galician and Asturian all do it as well, so it's likely something from early Romance.  It's fairly interchangeable though in formal writing people tend to eschew it.

Comment: Do you have any link to learn more about this? I haven't seen it anywhere online or in any book or dictionary

Comment: I've edited your post a bit and I've got one question: why have you left some part of the text in Spanish? Apart from the example phrases, I mean. Could you translate it, please? So the full post is coherent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is always safer to use the conditional:

- Si pudiera elegir, me **casaría** con ésta. (present counterfactual)

The imperfect past sounds colloquial and is not always safe to use:

- Si pudiera elegir, me **casaba** con ésta. (present counterfactual)

In [this book](https://books.google.com.ar/books?id=OMjV4stoXs4C&pg=PA159&lpg=PA159&dq=%22preterito%20imperfecto%20hipotetico%22&source=bl&ots=pOUveMpS3i&sig=ACfU3U1bBbiwciFyDJpbvMbxh4w-r8BiUA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiTpNDlmaDpAhWCHbkGHeEjBuUQ6AEwBHoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22preterito%20imperfecto%20hipotetico%22&f=false) reference can be found to this use of the tense, known as "pretérito imperfecto hipotético o condicional":

[image: pretérito imperfecto hipotético o condicional]

Its use in the condition is only accepted when it is also used in the result. In this case, the sentence will be understood as past counterfactual:

- Si **sabía**, **venía** antes (I I'd known, I would've come earlier).

Comment: No creo que lo llamaría *erróneo*, dado que es uso antiguo y no solo panhispánico sino panibérico.  Pero concuerdo totalmente que no suena muy formal.

Comment: @user0721090601 Es erróneo su uso en la prótasis cuando hay condicional en la apódosis. Sólo es correcto su uso (aunque coloquial) cuando hay impertecto en ambas partes de la oración condicional. Edité mi respuesta en tal sentido.

Comment: Ups, leí demasiado rápido

Comment: No sé si en las fuentes hay algo más sobre esto, pero es de notar que se habla siempre de una combinación de condición y resultado, que es como efectivamente yo siempre oigo este uso. El condicional se puede usar solo ("Me pegaría un baño"), el imperfecto como condicional no, salvo en una elipsis bien marcada ("Ay, si sabía... Pero no sabía.")

Comment: @pablodf76 Es verdad: siempre se usa en el marco de oraciones condicionales. A lo sumo, la prótasis puede estar implícita: A. ¿Que harías en mi lugar (si estuvieras en mi lugar)? B: Yo en tu lugar me casaba.